# ASP.NET Core OData $expand with FluentValidation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to query with OData using the **$expand** operator but when using **AbstractValidator** inheritance, I'm receiving a *System.InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type*. However without **AbstractValidator** inheritance, the query go successfully.

The request I'm trying to execute is:
https://localhost:44316/developer/oncontextpaging?$expand=Goal

The full code is on my github, the configuration is already set, just need to run: **update-database** and simulate the above request.
https://github.com/adlerpagliarini/ODataSamples/tree/1643ca615de346613081c34a58f1166ec741c42b

```
public abstract class Identity<TEntity> : AbstractValidator<TEntity>
{
    protected Identity() { }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Developer : Identity<Developer>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Goal Goal { get; set; }
}

public class Goal : Identity<Goal>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```